# Defining an array of methods

Tags: java, lambda

I'm working on a small Image Processing program. It has a GUI, and I'd like to bind each button to a different method. To do this I've decided to create an array of methods, but, so far I can't make it work. I've tried using an anonymous class but It hasn't worked for me. My code:

```
public class ImageProcessor {
    void blur(){
        System.out.println("blurring");
    }
    void sharpen(){
        System.out.println("sharpening");
    }
}

public class GUI {
    private ImageProcessor imager = new ImageProcessor();
    private ImageProcessor[] LAMBDAS = new ImageProcessor[]{
            public void blur(){imager.blur();}} // one of my failed attempts
    }
```

Once the blur button is pressed, for example, I'd like to bind the first item of the array to it, in this case, the blur method. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your `ImageProcessor` is not a lambda. It would be more something like `Runnable lambda = () -> imager.blur();`. But the array seems a bit irrelevant...you might want to continue a bit with your design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the array, but you also have to create new `ImageProcessor` objects within the outer braces using the `new` keyword:

```
class GUI {
    private ImageProcessor imager = new ImageProcessor();
    private ImageProcessor[] LAMBDAS = new ImageProcessor[] {
            //LAMBDAS[0]
            new ImageProcessor() {
                public void blur() {
                    imager.blur();
                }
            },

            //LAMBDAS[1]
            new ImageProcessor() {
                public void blur() {
                    imager.blur();
                }
            } };
}
```

You can also omit the `new ImageProcessor[]` part of the array initialization syntax if preferred, and just use the braces.

---

The above addresses just the syntax error causing compiler errors. As a side note, this is not how event handlers are typically bound to even sources. The array doesn't help you in this case. If you had (for example) *multiple buttons performing similar events with different arguments*, then perhaps you would have needed an array.

In your case, however, it should be enough to register events by adding a listener without compiling an array of `ImageProcessor` objects, with each `ImageProcessor` doing one and only one thing (i.e., one of `blur()`, `sharpen()`, etc.).

Comment: Thanks! Is this a good solution in your opinion? I feel like eventually I may add many actions, so many many new objects feel wrong for me. Perhaps I should abandon this idea and redesign?

Comment: @Omri.B I've added a comment about that at the bottom of the answer. I think you would need just to register your processors one at a time, for specific actions. No need for arrays in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this can work.

What you can do is using reflection, see this tutorial from Oracle: https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javareflection.html

However I would do that only if really necessary because it will avoid many checks at compile time and runs slower than normal method calls.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the reply. Do you have an idea of how I can achieve something similar to what i'm after?

Comment: No, unless you use reflection, but that is far away from your array.